# Wpf Caliburn.Micro pressing Close button stops controls update from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Why wpf control stops updating when I press and hold Window Close button? I'm using dotnet472. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Implement your own custom caption buttons. This is not related to Caliburn.Micro by the  way.

Comment: That worked. I tried https://mahapps.com/docs/guides/quick-start. Mah apps have their own caption buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this would to be implement your own custom caption buttons.

As a side note, the issue is not related to Caliburn.Micro.